# How can I modify where my File object's .isFile() or .exists() methods checks for said file?

Tags: java, file, file-exists

I was stuck for a few hours because in my conditional loop, the .isFile or .exists methods always returned false.. even when the file DID exist.

I wondered if it could be the string that I had passed to my file on initialization was being overwritten somehow.. but that wasn't the case, as I suspected.

It turned out that the directory or path the .isFile and .exists() methods look into are

`C:\Users\MyComputerName\workspace\NameOfMyJavaProject\` directory.

This is the default where all of my stuff is stored. And so it all then clicked, it made sense why  my boolean variable always returned false and allowed the creation of the same named file.. because it would look into the directory I posted above, NOT where I had the files being created.. Because I have the files created in my `F:\` drive.

What could I do so that I could have the .isFile() and .exists() methods look into my `F:\` drive?

Comment: Could you show us some code? Your question as it stands does not make a lot of sense. `File::exists` is not hardcoded to look at some particular path.

Comment: Code is messy so I'm trying to save you all the trouble.. but 

the explenation I gave to Matt Clark should suffice.

And since it's not hard coded.. then where DOES it look if the file exists?

Oh and I'd like to add that My file is written via

`writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("F:\\"+ text +".txt"), "utf-8"));`

So I can't do what Makky suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Boolean exists = new File("F:\testFile.txt").exists();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I found out that it's how I created the File.

Answer (score 1):

To me this does not make much sense, but I will take a go anyway.

The `.exists` and `.isFile` method do not refer to a single point all the time, it is the file that it has been set to.

```
File f = new File("C:\FileOne.txt");
if(f.exists())
    System.out.println("FileOne Exists at " + f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Alright.

When my `File` object called `checkFile` calls a method `.getAbsolutePath();` 
the path that is returned is `C:\Users` etc.

HOWEVER, I have a method that CREATES this file into the F:\  path /directory
So lets say I create a file called "Phone number" and this is .txt file and it contains my phone number
When I try and create a .txt file again that is called "Phone number"(same name) the boolean variable should return true.. but it returns FALSE and I assume it is because the `checkFile.isFile()` method looks into a different place than where the file is actually created.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Makky helpd me out a lot.

When I created the `File` object called `checkFile` to only return a `true` or `false` via

`boolean yesOrNo = checkFile.isFile();`

I created it simply as `File checkFile = new File():`

the solution was to do the following

create the file varialbe as `File checkFile = new File("F:\\");`

basically when I created the checkFile object, it was defaulted to where all my java projects are, unlike my file, which was created at a specific place.

All I had to do was change how I created the File object, as well.

I Know my explenation is weird so if anyone, months or years down the road needs me to clarify this, just bump the thread, I'll make sure to talk to you one on one if needed.

Again, thanks to Makky and everyone else that chimed in.